# WSO2 Identity server with ASP .NET and WIF

Tags: asp.net, wso2, claims-based-identity, federated-identity, wso2-identity-server

We are looking into Microsoft ASP .NET(WS-Federation with windows identity foundation) interoperability with WSO2 identity server. I posted the issue on the forum 14 weeks ago (http://wso2.org/forum/thread/14221) but have not got any response on the thread yet. I would really appreciate if I get some guidance on how to configure the passive STS in context to an ASP .NET client using WS-Federation protocol (windows identity foundation) for the claim based security model. In our last investigation session, we found Stonehenge project (http://incubator.apache.org/stonehenge/) as an example closest to what we want to achieve but identity server version 3.2.0 had the Passive STS feature missing which I hope has been added back to version 3.2.2.

Q1 - Can you please confirm if WSO2 identity server has got full support of WS-Federation protocol? (If yes please provide related documents, if no please suggest best alternative for Microsoft identity foundation interoperability)

Q2 - Can you please provide a guidance and a sample of how to use passive STS feature in context of an ASP .NET application using Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)?

Q3- How to administer claims in identity server to be consumed in ASP .NET application?

Answer (score 2):

Q1 - WSO2 Identity Server does not have full support for WS-Federation specification.

Q2 - Identity Server has support for PassiveSTS and we are in process of writing an article on that. That will be available by next week. Will post this link here once its available.

Q3 - Identity Server has the Claim Management feature. Where you can add your own claim dialect.

Comment: hi Prabath,Thanks for your reply. Q1 - What is missing regarding WS-Federation, Q2-I would be desperately waiting for the article. Q3 - Can you please pass a link on claim management feature documentation which shows how to use this feature for an ASP .NET client?

Comment: Apologies for the delay.. We have successfully integrated IS with MS Sharepoint via PassiveSTS.. and article seems be delayed due to some integration issues with Stonehenge project.. I will work on it and get you back soon on the article.. If you would like I can setup a demo of Identity Server... Please let me know..

Comment: Here comes the article http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/12/configuring-wso2-identity-server-passive-sts-aspnet-client